# Configuration Error in Azure IoT Edge installation - "configuration has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - Error"

Tags: azure, docker, azure-iot-edge

Version details

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- aziot-edge: bionic,now 1.2.3-1 amd64
- aziot-identity-service: bionic,now 1.2.2-1 amd64
- docker: Docker version 20.10.8+azure, build 3967b7d28e15a020e4ee344283128ead633b3e0c

Verifying the installation shows that the aziot-identityd is in "Down-activating" state

```
# sudo iotedge system status
System services:
    aziot-edged             Running
    aziot-identityd         Down - activating
    aziot-keyd              Running
    aziot-certd             Running
    aziot-tpmd              Ready

aziot-identityd is in a bad state because:
aziot-identityd.service: Down - activating : Printing the last 10 log lines.
-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-11-06 12:29:56 IST, end at Fri 2021-09-10 19:07:13 IST. --
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN aziot-identityd[1871]: 2021-09-10T13:37:10Z [INFO] - Could not reconcile Identities with current device data. Reprovisioning.
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN aziot-identityd[1871]: 2021-09-10T13:37:10Z [INFO] - Updated device info for Edge1.
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN aziot-identityd[1871]: 2021-09-10T13:37:10Z [ERR!] - Failed to provision with IoT Hub, and no valid device backup was found: Hub client error
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN aziot-identityd[1871]: 2021-09-10T13:37:10Z [ERR!] - service encountered an error
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN aziot-identityd[1871]: 2021-09-10T13:37:10Z [ERR!] - caused by: Hub client error
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN aziot-identityd[1871]: 2021-09-10T13:37:10Z [ERR!] - caused by: internal error
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN aziot-identityd[1871]: 2021-09-10T13:37:10Z [ERR!] -    0: <unknown>
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN aziot-identityd[1871]:    1: <unknown>
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN systemd[1]: aziot-identityd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 10 19:07:10 vm-DevIoTEdge1-poc-CentIN systemd[1]: aziot-identityd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

iotedge check shows 2 configuration related errors:

```
# iotedge check --verbose

Configuration checks (aziot-identity-service)
---------------------------------------------
√ keyd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ certd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ tpmd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ identityd configuration is well-formed - OK
√ daemon configurations up-to-date with config.toml - OK
√ identityd config toml file specifies a valid hostname - OK
√ aziot-identity-service package is up-to-date - OK
√ host time is close to reference time - OK
√ preloaded certificates are valid - OK
√ keyd is running - OK
√ certd is running - OK
√ identityd is running - OK
× read all preloaded certificates from the Certificates Service - Error
    could not load cert with ID "aziot-edged-trust-bundle"

    Caused by:
        parameter "id" has an invalid value
        caused by: not found
√ read all preloaded key pairs from the Keys Service - OK
√ ensure all preloaded certificates match preloaded private keys with the same ID - OK

Connectivity checks (aziot-identity-service)
--------------------------------------------
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub AMQP port - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub MQTT port - OK

Configuration checks
--------------------
√ aziot-edged configuration is well-formed - OK
√ configuration up-to-date with config.toml - OK
√ container engine is installed and functional - OK
× configuration has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - Error
    SocketError - SocketErrorCode (TimedOut) : Operation timed out
    One or more errors occurred. (Got bad response: )
        caused by: docker returned exit code: 1, stderr = SocketError - SocketErrorCode (TimedOut) : Operation timed out
                   One or more errors occurred. (Got bad response: )
√ aziot-edge package is up-to-date - OK
√ container time is close to host time - OK
‼ DNS server - Warning
    Container engine is not configured with DNS server setting, which may impact connectivity to IoT Hub.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-dns for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting DNS server per module in the Edge deployment.
        caused by: Could not open container engine config file /etc/docker/daemon.json
        caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
√ production readiness: container engine - OK
‼ production readiness: logs policy - Warning
    Container engine is not configured to rotate module logs which may cause it run out of disk space.
    Please see https://aka.ms/iotedge-prod-checklist-logs for best practices.
    You can ignore this warning if you are setting log policy per module in the Edge deployment.
        caused by: Could not open container engine config file /etc/docker/daemon.json
        caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
× production readiness: Edge Agent's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Error
    Could not check current state of edgeAgent container
        caused by: docker returned exit code: 1, stderr = Error: No such object: edgeAgent
× production readiness: Edge Hub's storage directory is persisted on the host filesystem - Error
    Could not check current state of edgeHub container
        caused by: docker returned exit code: 1, stderr = Error: No such object: edgeHub
√ Agent image is valid and can be pulled from upstream - OK

Connectivity checks
-------------------
√ container on the default network can connect to upstream  AMQP port - OK
√ container on the default network can connect to upstream HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ container on the default network can connect to upstream MQTT port - OK
√ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream AMQP port - OK
√ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream HTTPS / WebSockets port - OK
√ container on the IoT Edge module network can connect to upstream MQTT port - OK
30 check(s) succeeded.
2 check(s) raised warnings.
4 check(s) raised errors.
```

TOML file has only the manual provisioning with connection string.

Comment: I am going through same problem on redhat machine which is lying behind proxy server. I cannot open the iothub to accept all public network. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question like too many times while I was working with an enterprise environment. My finding is more related to the environment and security aspect of the whole system.

For my case, my working environment was RedHat Linux and Azure is hosted on-prem with added layer of proxy server. Only one piece of advice to solve most common issues in such environment is to give all necessary permissions of rwx (read, write, all).

Pinpointing the problem asked, the identity daemon is failing because the aziot trust bundle is not loading properly.

```html
read all preloaded certificates from the Certificates Service - Error
    could not load cert with ID "aziot-edged-trust-bundle"
```

Check the certificate is properly setup to use device identity certificate.

Second error is related to daemon management socket:

```html
× configuration has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - Error
    SocketError - SocketErrorCode (TimedOut) : Operation timed out
    One or more errors occurred. (Got bad response: )
        caused by: docker returned exit code: 1, stderr = SocketError - SocketErrorCode (TimedOut) : Operation timed out
                   One or more errors occurred. (Got bad response: )
```

This can be resolved by manually giving ownership permission to mgmt.sock at /var/lib/iotedge location.

Nevertheless, there may be a variety of reasons for iotedge dps to not work and further iotAgent and iotHub to not start. It is better to go to the root of the issue and start resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because my IOT Hub networks "Public network access" was set as "Disabled".

You can correct this by going the following:

1. Go to the Azure portal, and go to the IOT Hub resource in question.
2. Go to the Networking menu option.
   Change the "Public network access" to either "All Networks" or "Selected IP ranges", depending on your use case. Remember if you select "Selected IP ranges", you must add the VM/IOT devices ip address to the list of allowed IP addresses.

Comment: I checked the Networking settings of the IoT Hub in question and the "Public network access" is already set to "All networks". The issue is only with the IoT Edge v1.2. I tried installing IoT Edge v1.1 on another device and it got successfully installed and provisioned with IoT Hub.

Comment: Thanks, @vasanthbk Your comment saved much of the efforts today...